# Unprocessed in wordpress migrate

Tags: 7, migrations

I migrated Wordpress to Drupal 7 using [wordpress migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate)

What does this mean unprocessed -444?

Is that I have 444 articles are failed imported to Drupal?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you guested *unprocessed* show the number of items that this module detected but couldn't import .